# Javascript inside ASP.net literal not working on IE server but works on localhost

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, internet-explorer, localhost, windows-server-2008

Hi Stackoverflow community! I have a question in mind and I would like to solve it with your knowledge, thanks for reading this post. All ideas are welcome. Here is my situation:

1. I am working with ASP.net 4 WebForms.
2. I built a user control .ascx whichs has many literals.
3. Those literals writes javascript in my user control.
4. On localhost works perfect! (yes, here we go)
5. On the server works too! Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome, Opera Browser, even Safari But with **IE doesn't write just one literal**. I need that javascript in order to accomplish the feature.

Is the same code from  both sides (local and server) Do you have any idea in order to solve this issue?

Thank you again for reading this, have a great day.

Update

I realize that on IE shows:
div class and then ID
But in others browsers: div id class

Comment: Any error in developer console (F12 in browser)? There is more info needed to get some advice from other guys.

Comment: Thank you Dzoukr. I used F12 in many browsers. There are no errors, but one detail: on IE shows div,class, id, in other browsers: div, id, class